# What's the point of "Smelt [slot] weapons"?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Team Fortress 2 has the following lines in *Crafting Items* menu:

- **Smelt primary weapons** (2 of the same primary weapon)
- **Smelt secondary weapons** (2 of the same primary weapon)
- **Smelt melee weapons** (2 of the same melee weapon)
- **Smelt class weapons** (2 weapons used by the same class)

All these produce ***1* Scrap Metal**.

So, why are the first three items needed, if 2 of the same weapons are always used by the same class anyway?

Comment: This curiosity is also mentioned in [this wiki footnote](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Crafting#cite_note-0).

Comment: Actually only two of them are needed, because the shotgun is the only weapon shared across classes.

Comment: Note, as of [today's patch](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/July_18,_2011_Patch) the blueprints are removed. They must've read this ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go back and have a look at the [old version](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/index.php?title=Crafting&oldid=982) of the wiki page linked by @The Annoying Pyro, there is an explanation there:

> The Smelt Class Weapons blueprint was originally one Primary, Secondary, and Melee weapon of each class, but was then altered to allow any 3 (now 2) weapons from the same class, to accommodate the Engineer, Demoman, Spy, and at the time this change was made, the Sniper. This has made the blueprints marked with a dagger superfluous.

I'll try to find out why this was removed from the article.

Comment: Probably due to the overhaul of the page after the Über Update revamped the crafting UI.

Comment: From today's patch notes: "Removed the redundant Smelt Primary/Secondary/Melee/Misc item blueprints"

Comment: @Raven: What's the protocol for situations like this? Edit the question? The answer? Leave it as it is?

Comment: @CruelCow - when the answer gets updated, by all means, edit the changes into your answer! The more up to date and complete our information, the better.